# WPF Bind textbox Text to another control property

Tags: wpf

I have a binding in XAML:

```
<TextBox Name="test" Text="{Binding Width, ElementName=brd2}"></TextBox>
```

where brd2 is a border control.

How can I do this in code?

Comment: you probably want ActualWIdth

Comment: Thnx ASh. This is what I am asking.

Comment: ASh. It is not working. Can you please explain a little more to me?